# How to exclude CSRF token for specific domain?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I am hoping to disable CSRF verification tokens for a specific domain. For example, my EC2 instances. This is so that I can run live-cross browser testing on my EC2 instance without any issues.

I've found a lot of info on updating the `VerifyCsrfToken` in the middleware directory for specific routes within the app, but nothing on how to check the host or domain. I can use `/*` in my protected URIs.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
    * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
    *
    * @var array
    */

    protected $except = [
        '/*'
    ];
}
```

However, for obvious reasons, I would prefer not to use this approach.

I am using a standard Laravel 5.3 setup, so have usual middleware files that come with this framework in use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can override the `isExceptArray` function and add additional logic in it. Look at the base code for the BaseVerifier (`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check the host used to make a request in the CSRF middleware and act accordingly. Add the following in your **VerifyCsrfToken** class:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->getHost() == 'some.host.without.csrf.protection') {
        // skip CSRF check
        return $next($request);
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this returns an error message `Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request, $next) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request, Closure $next)`... any thoughts?

Comment: Add `use Closure;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Oops my mistake. Now displaying, `Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\parent()`

Comment: Updated, a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is to override `isExceptArray` function which is written in the parent class `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`.

Just write your logic in there.