# Disable CSRF token from specific ip/domain

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-9

I want to exclude CSRF token for login from specific ip/domain, so client could login to the website without input their credential again. Now I could only exclude the URI.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        '/login',
    ];
}
```

I tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189446/5597724 but the page return 419.

Below solution also not work.

```
    protected $except = [
        'http://ip',
        'ip',
    ];
```

Comment: The functionality of CSRF token has nothing to do with the user force to input their credential. Maybe what you want to do is use an API routing ?!

Comment: You can do it with middleware and third party IP location library like IPDATA. https://github.com/kielabokkie/laravel-ipdata